# How to edit a selected ng-repeat element using another controller and view?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following list of elements with edit button in front of each element.

View:

```
<div ng-controller="studentController" >
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="student in controller.students">
                <td>{{student}}</td>
                <td><a href="#/app/student/edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a></td>              
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

studentController:

```
myApp.controller('studentController', function($http, $scope) {
    var self = this;

    $http.get('students/').then(function(response) {

        self.students = response.data.students;

    });                           
});
```

When I click on the Edit button I should be able to edit the student details such as grade and marks in another page. I am not sure how to pass the selected student to the edit page. How can I achieve this using AngularJS?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which router you are using, you can pass params as such (ui-router):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="student in students">
        <a ui-sref="student.detail({ id: student.id })">{{ student.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You will need a route for 'student.detail' state

```
$stateProvider.state('student', {
 template: ...,
 controller: 'studentController'
})


$stateProvider.state('student.detail', {
    url: "/student/:studentId",
    templateUrl: 'student.detail.html',
    controller: function ($stateParams, StudentService) {
        console.log($stateParams.studentId);
        $scope.student = StudentService.get($stateParams.studentId)
    }
})
```

**Edit (ngRoute):**

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) { 
  $routeProvider
  .when('/app/student',{ 
      templateUrl : 'app/components/student/student.html', 
      controller: 'studentController', 
  // route for edit student       
  }).when('/app/student/edit/:studentid',{ 
      templateUrl : 'app/components/student/editStudent.html',                        
      controller: 'editStudentControllerCtrl', 
  // route for other      
  }).otherwise('/');
```

Within editStudentControllerCtrl you can access studentId through $routeParams

```
controller('editStudentControllerCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams)    
{
 $scope.studentId = $routeParams.studentId;
  // use studentId to fetch and update students
 });
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

Comment: My route.js looks like this:
myApp.config(
  
 function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    }).when('/app/student',{
    templateUrl : 'app/components/student/student.html',
    controller: 'studentController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
   // route for edit student
   }).when('/app/student/edit',{
    templateUrl : 'app/components/student/editStudent.html',
    controller: 'editStudentControllerCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'controller'          
 // route for other
   }).otherwise('/');

Comment: Do I have to create an Angular Service for this?

Comment: View my edits for ngRoute.  Using $http within the controller will work, however, a better way is to use a service to encapsulate and abstract your model (i.e student) such that it is easily reusable (and consistent) throughout your application.